# Hide section headers in StickyListHeaders

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using [StickyListHeaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) library in my project.I have added section headers in the app and it works also.But for some condition i want to hide section headers.
How can i achieve this please guide me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in getHeaderView - set HeaderView.Visibility(View.GONE);

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. header.setVisibility(View.GONE) doesn't work.

Solution is:

layout for header view must be with  layout_height = "wrap_content"

and then, for content of this layout, you can setVisibility(View.GONE)

Answer (score 0):

I used same Adapter for two layouts

Layout with header

```
<se.emilsjolander.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersListView
android:id="@+id/listview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

Layout without header

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
```

onCreateView:

```
if (needHeader) {
    mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ly_list_with_header, null);
    stickyListHeadersListView = (StickyListHeadersListView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
} else {
    mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ly_without_header, null);
    listView = (ListView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
}
```

on task result:

```
if (needHeader) {
    stickyListHeadersListView.setAdapter(adapter);
} else {
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```